# How to set input length size limit using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hello please I created a form which user can only type from 1-100 most people usually modify it to 300 using the inspect developers option, Please how can I create it with Javascript to avoid being modified easily.
Example.

```html
<input type="number" minlength="1" maxlength="100">
```

Comment: When validating the form, check if the length is `> 100` when submitting on the client, or when POST-ing on the server. There is no way to prevent someone from manipulating the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to avoid a user to change maxlength on an input field using browser console, maybe you can use Javascript, but someone could also bypass this control, the only solution is:

1. Keep a control like your
2. Return an error from the server if the field inserted contains more than 100 characters or an incorrect value

If you want to try the Javascript solution, you can try using the input onChange event, but it will not change a lot.

Remember that, someone could also send from the browser console an http request to your server, so protect the server!